# Estimating AIC for data subsets

Tags: aic, model-comparison

When modelling data that contain groups, I want to test whether the groups are different and therefore should be modeled with different parameters. If a simple model for the whole dataset is y ~ x, and the groups are denoted by parameter z, a model that allows the groups to differ is y ~ x*z. It is straightforward to use AIC to compare this group model with y ~ x. If there are 2 groups, the parameter estimates from the group model can also be obtained by splitting the dataset by z, and fitting a model to each data subset:

```
model a: y[z=0] ~ x[z=0] 
model b: y[z=1] ~ x[z=1]
```

However, when fitted in R, the AIC(group model: a,b) is not equal to AIC(model a) + AIC(model b). See the code below. I checked with both glm and gam (mgcv).

I expected that the AIC(group model) would be the same as AIC(model a) + AIC(model b), because the same data are being used on both sides, the parameter estimates are the same on both sides, and the numbers of parameters are the same on both sides. But the AICs on the two sides are different. Since AIC = 2k - 2 x ln(L), this must mean that the likelihood estimates are different, but I don't understand why.

Could someone please explain why they differ?

```
x=1:10
y=x+rnorm(10)
z = rep(c(F,T),5)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,z)
mod2 <- glm(y ~ x,data=dat[dat$z,])
mod3 <- glm(y ~ x,data=dat[!dat$z,])
mod4 <- glm(y ~ x*z,data=dat)
AIC(mod4) # the combined group model 
# [1] 38.10184

AIC(mod2) + AIC(mod3) # a separate model for each group
# [1] 40.08271 # in 10000 trials, this number was larger than AIC(mod4) 84% of the time

sum(dnorm(mod4$residuals))
# [1] 2.725178
sum(dnorm(mod2$residuals)) + sum(dnorm(mod3$residuals))
# [1] 2.725178

pred1 <- predict(mod1,newdata=dat)
pred2 <- predict(mod2,newdata=dat)
pred3 <- predict(mod3,newdata=dat)
pred4 <- predict(mod4,newdata=dat)

windows();
plot(dat$x,pred1,type="l",xlim=c(0,11),ylim=c(0,11))
lines(dat$x,pred2,col=2)
lines(dat$x,pred3,col=3)
points(dat$x,pred4)
```

Answer (score 2):

AIC, as it turns out, is related to the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Limitations_of_entropy_as_information_content) of a single dataset, which is a measure of self-information. Entropy is not relative information content and is not a comparative measure between datasets. It has none of the properties of, for example, temperature difference, which would indicate in which direction information would flow. Self-information does not have nice properties and can only be used for comparing differing models fit to the same dataset.

Different subsets have differing entropies and cannot be compared using AIC.

Comment: Are you answering the actual question -- *Could someone please explain why they differ?* -- or is this more of a comment helping to better understand AIC? (If the latter, then it should be posted as a comment, IMHO.)

Comment: @RichardHardy I added that in explicitly. It was implied by context before. Entropy is not a comparative measurement, it is an absolute measurement  within any data set. The answer I give is the answer. It is a lot more fundamental than AIC on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Transforming_data), which states "The AIC values of the candidate models must all be computed with the same data set," without the slightest indication of why that is.

Comment: The question is not about comparing AICs of models on different data sets. Check the question carefully: *when fitted in R, the AIC(group model) is not equal to AIC(model a) + AIC(model b). <...> I expected that they would be the same, because the parameter estimates (and therefore the log likelihood) and numbers of parameters are identical, but they are not. Could someone please explain why they differ?*

Comment: @RichardHardy Entropy is non-linear.

Comment: @RichardHardy The question states "AIC for data subsets." You are expecting that y~x*z is the same data set as y~x? Please explain.

Comment: The OP just updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy, this is helpful but not entirely clear to me. I've edited the question to make it more apparent that the same data are being used on both sides.

Comment: Sorry I meant @Carl

Comment: In the group model, z is used directly (y ~ x*z). In the separated models, z is used to split the dataset. In my interpretation, this means that the same information is provided in both approaches.

Comment: @SDH What it looks like to me is that you are anticipating that $AIC(a,b)=AIC(a)+AIC(b)$. And, I am having trouble understanding why you are expecting that.

Comment: @Carl, probably by analogy to log-likelihood (my guess).

Comment: @RichardHardy OK, but, the example furnished in the question disproves that notion, does it not? Next, AIC is an index, not a measurement. There is no associative property for AIC. Sure, one might presume independent information to be additive. I do not think there is independence here, what do you think?

Comment: @Carl, yes, the example in the question clearly disproves the notion, which is what motivated my question. I'm not asking whether they are the same. I'm asking why they are different.

Comment: Entropy has the dimension of [energy divided by temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Entropy_of_a_system), which has a unit of joules per kelvin (J/K) in the International System of Units. One cannot add entropies.

Comment: @SDH Maybe try averaging AICs, that will not be correct either, but it is likely to be closer.

Comment: Thanks @Carl. The comments about entropy are interesting and useful. AIC is related to entropy, but it's hard to know which arguments about entropy are transferable to AIC. Also, I don't see how averaging AICs could be applicable in this case.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for your comments. I've edited the question again to try and clarify it. I'm hoping for an explanation that addresses the likelihood.

Comment: @SDH Would you show the values that you did get, please?

Comment: @carl, I just added some values to the code section. I think I've now answered it for myself. Although the individual residuals are the same for both approaches, the variance estimates differ, and this feeds through into the likelihoods and the AIC values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47027/discussion-between-sdh-and-carl).

Comment: i don’t understand why the OP claims that „the numbers of parameters are the same on both sides“. whatever number of parameters are estimated, that number appears twice in all the three AICs and therefore twice in AIC(group model) but four times in AIC(model a) + AIC(model b). therefore it's not even necessary to consider the likelihood part of the AIC to see that it cannot be additive on subsets of the data, is it?

Comment: @schotti In effect, I agree. Subset analysis having multiple datasets properly uses cross validation techniques, which excludes AIC; a reparameterization comparison technique for a single dataset.

Comment: @schotti One can compare two different models that have the same number of parameters, e.g. $y=m\, x+b$, or $y=c\,e^{-\lambda\,x}$ both having two parameters: $\{m,b\}$ and $\{c,\lambda\}$, respectively, and compare the goodness-of-fit using AIC, provided the dataset is the same, and $N>300$ or at least large.

Answer (score 1):

When the dataset is split into parts, the sum of the likelihoods (and therefore the AIC's) won't be the same as the likelihood of the group model, because the variances in the likelihood equations differ. The variance estimate in each part uses a subset of the data, while the variance estimate in the group analysis uses all of the data.

Running the model in the question 10000 times, the sum of AIC(mod2) and AIC(mod3) is about one unit larger than AIC(mod4), the group AIC, on average. The difference in each run is random (variance is fairly unstable) and in 16% of runs the group AIC is larger.